# how to get size of folder including apparent size of sparse files? (du is too slow)

Tags: linux, kvm, du

I have a folder containing a lot of KVM qcow2 files, they are all sparse files.
Now I need to get the total size of folder, the qcow2 file size should be counted as apparent size(not real size).

for example:

image: c9f38caf104b4d338cc1bbdd640dca89.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 100G (107374182400 bytes)
disk size: 3.3M
cluster_size: 65536

the image should be treated as 100G but not 3.3M

originally I use statvfs() but it can only return real size of the folder. then I switch to 'du --apparent-size', but it's too slow given I have 10000+ files and it takes almost 5 minutes to caculate.

anybody knows a fast way that can get the size of folder counting qcow2's virtual size? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to find out this information without `stat()`ing every file in the directory. It is slow if you have this many files in a single directory. `stat()` needs to retrieve the inode of every single file.

Adding more memory might help due to caching.

Comment: Yes, I finally realized the truth

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

`find images/ -name "*.qcow2" -exec qemu-img info {} \; | grep virtual | cut -d"(" -f2 | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'`

Comment: yes it works, but still slow. The reason is the same as du, they are both walking the file system. I need a way that can read the size of folder from somewhere just like statvfs, plus it's able to count virtual size

Comment: @zx_wing Most Unix/Linux file systems do not store that information, so you can't just read it - it has to be computed, which requires walking the tree. Statistics like that *are* kept on a file-system level, so if your tree is the only thing in that file system, the statvfs route should give you that information, but if your tree is only part of a file system or if it spans several file systems, it must be computed.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Unix*ish OSes provide a way to retrieve the stats of all entries of a directory in one step.  This also needs to look at all inodes but probably it can be done optimized in the file system driver itself and thus might be faster.

Apparently you are not looking for a way to do this using system calls from C, so I guess a feasible approach could be to use Python.  There you have access to this feature using the function `scandir()` in module `os`.