# Check size of big directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have 6 very big directorys and once a day I would like to check size each of this directories for my monitoring. Now I'm using `du -s` command but it take many time and significantly slows my server. Is any different better way to do this?

Comment: There is none
But you could check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961607/how-to-get-size-of-folder-including-apparent-size-of-sparse-files-du-is-too-sl) question: and also [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/529338/du-command-takes-way-too-long-to-run).

Comment: Maybe run `du` with added `nice`ness.

Comment: @Idos - Unfortunately, the directories are so big and I do not have enough space for backup

Comment: "I do not have enough space for backup" -- unless we're talking trash data and/or a RAID 1 setup here, *get some way to backup*. Harddrives *do* fail. `rm -rf` commands *do* delete the wrong directory tree. Accidents *do* happen. Believe me, you *don't* want to experience the pain of realizing you just *lost* important, possibly non-replaceable data. Get e.g. an external USB disk, they're dirt cheap these days and can be locked away; then *backup*. Better yet, create a backup *scheme* and backup *regularly*, *religiously*. At least those parts of your drive that would really *hurt* to lose.

Comment: You might check out inotify as an on-going ( runtime ) low impact monitor.  Ref:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html  ( there are many more and better docs, that's just one.  there are also some command lines tools inotify-tools ( example package name ).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on circumstances you could put those directories on seperate *partitions*, the "used" size of which you can check very quickly with `df`.

This, of course, means that the directories are limited to the size of their respective partitions, which could be a pain. Hence the "depending on circumstances".

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to use partition :(

Comment: @henio180: Well, it's your only bet of being faster than `du` I am afraid. At least to my knowledge.